# logic of canceling movement in time based animation

Tags: javascript, animation, math

I have designed a movement engine in my simple game where you have certain coordinates `(x,y)` and by clicking you can go to whatever destination `(x,y)`. The idea is that you have `speed` and `fuel consumption`, also entire movement is time-based. So at the end, if you decide to go from point A to point B, it will take X amount of time (determined by speed) and X amount of fuel (determined by consumption). The problem i am facing is precision in calculations and probably not the best logic of stoping the travel upon reaching the destination.

Calculations being made are correct, but their precision is causing some issues.

In the demo i included can be seen that my current canceling logic is producing leftovers (for example 20 litres of fuel should be burned but i am left with 0.12...):

```
if ( Math.floor( this.distance ) === 0 ) {
```

while my previous one never ends (as it can never get ideally to 0 without decimal places):

```
if ( this.distance > 0 ) {
```

My question is, how my code can be improved in the way that the travel always ends in correct point and fuel is always at the state it should be.

```js
const tools = {
 distance: (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)),
 rftv: (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
};

this.fuel = 200;
this.x = 100;
this.y = 50;
this.rad = 0; // radian angle between current and destination
this.speed = 100; // 100 pixels per second
this.consumption = 10; // 10 liters of fuel per 100 pixels
this.destination = {
 x: 220,
 y: 140
};

/*
Based on above

distance : 150
time : ( distance / speed ) => 150 / 100 => 1.5s
fuel : ( distance / consumption ) => 150 / 10 => 15 liters

So to summary, between two points we have 150 pixels of distance,
this trip should take 1.5s and burn 15 liters of fuel
*/

this.now = undefined;
this.delta = undefined;
this.then = Date.now();

this.setDelta = function() {
 this.now = Date.now();
 this.delta = (this.now - this.then) / 1000;
 this.then = this.now;
};

this.update = function() {
 this.rad = tools.rftv(
  { x: this.x, y: this.y },
  { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y }
 );
  
  let step = this.speed * this.delta;
 this.x += Math.cos(this.rad) * step;
 this.y += Math.sin(this.rad) * step;

 this.fuel -= step / this.consumption;
};

this.move = function() {
 this.distance = tools.distance(
  { x: this.x, y: this.y },
  { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y }
 );
 
 if ( Math.floor( this.distance ) === 0 ) {
  clearInterval(tsid);
  console.log('done', this.x, this.y, this.fuel, this.distance, '[ ' + (Date.now() - startedAt) + ' ]');
 } else {
  this.setDelta();
  this.update();
  console.log('going', this.x, this.y, this.fuel, this.distance, '[ ' + (Date.now() - startedAt) + ' ]');
 }
};



let tsid;
let startedAt = Date.now();
tsid = setInterval(function() {
 this.move();
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your object always travels directly towards the target, there is no need for any trigonometry. Just use vector math.
- Logically `update` should call `move`, not the other way round.
- The distance calculation should be performed in the same function as the movement code.
- Check the distance in `move` and set a completion flag.
- Fuel used in one step = consumption (usage / pixel) **×** step size in pixels, so `this.fuel -= step / this.consumption;` is incorrect.

Code:

```
this.fuel = 200;
this.x = 100;
this.y = 50;
// no need for rad
this.speed = 100;
this.consumption = 10;
this.destination = {
    x: 220,
    y: 140
};
this.complete = false; // completion flag

...

// swap functions

this.update = function() {
    this.update();

    if (this.complete) {
        clearInterval(tsid);
        console.log('done', this.x, this.y, this.fuel, this.distance, '[ ' + (Date.now() - startedAt) + ' ]');
    } else {
        this.setDelta();
        this.move();
        console.log('going', this.x, this.y, this.fuel, this.distance, '[ ' + (Date.now() - startedAt) + ' ]');
    }
};

this.move = function() {
    let step = this.speed * this.delta;
    let dist = tools.distance(
        { x: this.x, y: this.y },
        { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y }
    );
    /*
       would be cleaner to replace this with:
       Math.hypot(this.destination.x - this.x, this.destination.y - this.y);
    */

    // check distance
    if (dist <= step) {
        step = dist;
        this.complete = true;
    }

    // vector math not trigonometry
    this.x += (this.destination.x - this.x) * (step / dist);
    this.y += (this.destination.y - this.y) * (step / dist);

    this.distance -= step;
    this.fuel -= step * this.consumption; // should be * not /
};

...

tsid = setInterval(function() {
    this.update();
}, 10);
```